# How to ignore .gitignore and list ALL UNTRACKED FILES

Tags: git

Google fails at this search. What is the flag to `git ls-files` but ignore the .gitignore file rules?

Comment: Just use `find`?

Comment: Or `git ls-files; git ls-files -o`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Git ignore working :**

1. Create a folder as .gitignore inside your git folder,
2. Then commit it to the git,
3. Add or drag & drop any file inside .gitignore folder to ignore it from being tracked.

**To list all untracked files :**

1. Create any file/folder.
2. Use : **git ls-files --others** Command to List out the untracked files in git,
3. Or You can use **git status** Command to see the status, If you have any new/Untracked Files it will list down as Untracked files.